# When does cublasInit() return a NOT_INITIALIZED status?

Tags: cuda, blas

during my cublas initialization, i get an error, i.e. not the wanted **CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS**.

Checking the returned status, i figured out that the returned status is **CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED** which is not listed as possible returns of that function.

Does anyone have an idea what may have caused that behavior?

Comment: Could you possibly show us a concise, compilable piece of code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi Talonmies, sorry, that is not easily possible, as this is part of a bigger project. The Project itself compiles well on one machine I do not have access to, and on my machine the above error happens at the very beginning initialization call of cublas. Maybe this is some sort of versioning problem. But i am most confused by the fact i catch a status that Nvidia states should not be returned by that routine... best

Comment: What version of CUDA, CUBLAS and driver are you running this on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CUBLAS 4.x documentation mentions CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED as error code for cublasCreate with the meaning "the CUDA Runtime initialization failed".
Can you verify that you have a valid CUDA context?

If so, did you create a valid CUBLAS context?
For CUBLAS 3.x and CUBLAS 4.x using the legacy API: did you call cublasInit while there is a CUDA context in the current thread active, and did it return CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS?
For CUBLAS 4.x with new API: did you call cublasCreate and did it return CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS? Are you using the handle created when calling cublas..._v2 methods?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your hint. I had a working environment, but as my PC and the Nvidia-Drivers (though not the CUDA SDK) are subject to autmatic institute-wide updates, they might have damaged my setup.